# C++ insert a html string in postgresql database

Tags: c++, sql, postgresql, c++11, libpqxx

I'm trying to insert an html string into a database column, but I'm having trouble with characters like quotes etc... which are inside the html. I'm using libpqxx as my C++ library to execute queries in the DB, and I'm using the function pqxx::quote() to add quotes between my string so that I don't have syntax troubles when I execute the insert query, but the problem is when I list the rows in the DB the html column shows only binary data. And I don't know why is that?
here is the sql for creating the table:

```
  CREATE TABLE html_table(ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,URL TEXT NOT NULL,PARSERS TEXT NOT NULL,HTML TEXT);
```

And here is the C++ code:

```
void PostgreDb::insertRow(const std::string url,
                          const std::string parsers,
                          const std::string html)
{
    work W(*c);
    std::string sql = "INSERT INTO "+ table +"(URL,PARSERS,HTML)" \
            "VALUES (\'"+ url.c_str() +"\',\'"+ parsers.c_str() +"\',"+ W.quote(html) +");";

    W.exec(sql);
    W.commit();
}
```

Result in the DB after this piece of code is executed:

```
mydb=# select url,parsers,html from html_table;
              url               |     parsers      |      html       
--------------------------------+------------------+-----------------
 http://www.lupiga.com/         | name description | \x1F\u008B\x08
 http://www.huffingtonpost.com/ | name keywords    | \x1F\u008B\x08
(2 rows)
```

Note: I would say that quote() is not reliable here, anyone knows a better way to solve this?

Edit:
After trying with raw literals.

```
void PostgreDb::insertRow(const std::string url,
                          const std::string parsers,
                          const std::string html)
{
    work W(*c);
    std::string raw = "\n"+ html +"\n";
    std::string sql = "INSERT INTO "+ table +"(URL,PARSERS,HTML)" \
            "VALUES (\'"+ url.c_str() +"\',\'"+ parsers.c_str() +"\',"+ W.quote(raw) +");";

    W.exec(sql);
    W.commit();
}
```

Still doesn't work:

```
mydb=# select url,parsers,html from html_table;
              url               |     parsers      |      html      
--------------------------------+------------------+----------------
                                |                  |
 http://www.lupiga.com/         | name description |               +
                                |                  | \x1F\u008B\x08
 http://www.huffingtonpost.com/ | name keywords    |               +
                                |                  | \x1F\u008B\x08
(2 rows)
```

Comment: You may try to use [raw string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) to make your life easier.

Comment: Welcome to SQL injection paradise! "Secury-holes-r-us: we hack your web sites for free"!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik https://xkcd.com/327/ :-) ...

Comment: The result of `quote(html)` can't be judged if  you don't tell what is in `html` in the first place.

Comment: Well, it's content downloaded from one of the links from the database. E.g.  http://www.huffingtonpost.com/, point is it's probably a large html containing all kinds of chars, quotes, double quotes, backslashes probably, etc. And as I see it if you try to store that kind of text in the DB, you'll get syntax errors from the DBMS (due to different meanings of these chars), that's why I used quote() here. Since, as I understood, it's purpose is to help in these situations?